# How to improve performance in cypher query with `OR`?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My query is:
`match (n :l1)-[r]-(n2 :l2) where n.id=10 OR n2.id=5 return n,n2,r`

I expect this to return all the elements that contains `n` or `n2` and have the given label.

I have indexes in both `n :li(id)` and `n2 :l2(id)` but in the profile it says that it is making a `NodeByLabelScan` with thousands of db hits... why?

The same query with `AND` does use the index.

EDIT: @StefanArmbruster solution of using `UNION` performs way better as it does each query separately and then merges the result without hitting the db. Millions of db hits to thousands :)

Comment: which version of Neo4j?

Comment: @StefanArmbruster I'm running 2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is a good candidate for using `UNION`:

```
MATCH (n:l1{id:10})-[r]-(n2)
RETURN n, r, n2
UNION
MATCH (n:l2{id:5})-[r]-(n2)
RETURN n, r, n2
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that and report back